# Can't install lighttpd on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lighttpd

I can't install lighttpd on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I did an update & upgrade and then:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ sudo apt install lighttpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lighttpd : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
fmf@kodi:~$
```

My sources.list:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe restricted multiverse
#deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe restricted multiverse
#deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe restricted multiverse
#deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe restricted multiverse


# Backports:
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse


# Canonical partner:
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
fmf@kodi:~$
```

My system:

fmf@kodi:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
fmf@kodi:~$ uname -a
 Linux kodi 4.15.0-44-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 14 11:26:59 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
fmf@kodi:~$

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to install the dependencies with `sudo apt install -f`!

Comment: Yep, no package to be installed.

Comment: i have stumbled upon the same sitiuation and the marked duplicated posts does not solve it. for the fix see https://askubuntu.com/a/1118711/74767