# lighttpd won't install - Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I've been trying to install `lighttpd` on my PC running Ubuntu 18.04. The error I keep getting is that it has unmet dependencies, namely `libssl1.1`. However, `libssl1.1` is already installed.

```
   $ sudo apt-get install lighttpd
      Reading package lists... Done
      Building dependency tree       
      Reading state information... Done
      Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
      requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
      distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
      or been moved out of Incoming.
      The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
      The following packages have unmet dependencies:
       lighttpd : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
      E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The output of `apt-cache policy libssl1.1` is

```
libssl1.1:
  Installed: 1.1.1a-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 1.1.1a-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.1a-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3 500
        500 http://zw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.0g-2ubuntu4 500
        500 http://zw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

I'm not sure if there's anything I might be missing here.

Comment: I know there are problems with recent versions of `libssl1.1`. You could try `sudo apt install libssl1.1` to see why exactly it is not going to be installed.

Comment: It's saying libssl1.1 is already installed ----- libssl1.1 is already the newest version (1.1.1a-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libssl1.1` to the question. It seems that you are using PPA.

Comment: Hi @N0rbert. I've added the output of `apt-cache policy libssl1.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two options:

- Try to install `libssl` manually (the exact version from official repository):

  ```
  sudo apt install libssl1.1=1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3
  ```
- Remove [`ppa:ondrej/php`](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) from the system:

  ```
  sudo apt install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php
  ```

  and then install `lighttpd`

  ```
  sudo apt install lighttpd
  ```

Comment: The top command worked for me and downgraded my libssl version. Then my installs went as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I downloaded the lighttpd .deb package and ran dpkg which gave some more insight:

```
libssl1.1:armhf (1.1.1a-2~20190131152537.8+stretch) breaks lighttpd (<< 1.4.49-2) and is installed.
```

So it looks like the libssl 1.1.1a package from deb.sury.org is too new for the lighttpd 1.4.45 that comes from debian. I removed that package source and downgraded libssl after which I could install lighttpd.
Alternatively you could try to get lighttpd 1.4.49 or later.

Comment: Please provide links to package in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

These days Ubuntu published their new long term supported version, 22.04, and it is not possible to install mongodb because they don’t support libssl1.1 anymore
**I found it best way**
**We can solve it by:**

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc |  gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb.gpg > /dev/null

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Comment: What is the point of adding both `amd64` and `arm64` archs?